# Changing sheet displayed with ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am dynamically creating an Excel workbook with multiple sheets using ClosedXML.  I am struggling changing the sheet selected back to the first sheet in the workbook after I am done generating the content and cannot find anything in the documentation on how to change the sheet that is displayed.  I have tried:

```
wb.Worksheet(1).Select();
```

This selects all of the cells in the worksheet, but it doesn't change the view back.

```
wb.Worksheet(1).Cells(1,1).Value = wb.Worksheet(1).Cells(1,1).Value
```

seems to set the value, but again doesn't change the view.

I have tried hiding the other sheets in hopes that it would auto select the visible sheets, but that does not seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to be looking at the following `wb.ActiveTab` do a google search on the following `How to set active sheet with Open XML`

Comment: ahhh, or in the case of ClosedXML, SetTabActive()

Comment: While wb.TabActive will get you the active worksheet. Just loop it with list of sheets and match bool value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using ClosedXML to set the Active Sheet to the first worksheet one would use this code:

```
wb.Worksheet(1).SetTabActive();
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that Andrew K's solution did not deselect previously selected tabs.  I wrote this extension to meet this requirement also:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetActiveSheet(this XLWorkbook workbook, IXLWorksheet sheetToSetActive)
    {
        foreach (var sheet in workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            var isCurrentSheet = sheet.Equals(sheetToSetActive);
            sheet.SetTabActive(isCurrentSheet);
            sheet.SetTabSelected(isCurrentSheet);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
var sheetToSetActive = wb.Worksheet(1);
wb.SetActiveSheet(sheetToSetActive);
```