# Activate last excel worksheet on worksheetlist with closedxml in c#

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

Is there any method for activate to last excel worksheet with closedxml in c# ?
Im already using `SetTabActive()` method but its not activate on worksheet bar.

```
workbook.Worksheet(83).SetTabActive().SetTabSelected();
workbook.SaveAs(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

when im saving excel file, it was opened like this:

[image]

But i would like to see like this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing sheet displayed with ClosedXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782327/changing-sheet-displayed-with-closedxml)

Comment: i already do that, but my question is  `Activate()`, its not about `Active()`